# Color ArrayPlot with custom colortable ~ ColorData or ColorRules

Tags: plotting, image-processing, color, list-manipulation

I have a map what I would like color according to predefined RGB colors. So first I make an array of the ImageData:

Download the attached data source here: [map](https://uploadfiles.io/gj68v), [colors](https://uploadfiles.io/8qyzn)

```
input = Import[
  "d:\\bitbucket\\diversity\\data\\nlcd_200x200.tif", {"GeoTIFF", 
   "Image"}] 

a = ImageData[input]*255;
```

Then I load the colors from a CSV:

```
Colors = ReadList[
  "d:\\bitbucket\\diversity\\data\\nlcd\\nlcd-colors.csv", {Word, 
   RGBColor[Word, Word, Word]}, WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}]
```

Then I try to use the colors to make a colorful map (it's bad...):

```
ArrayPlot[a, ColorRules -> {[[#1]] -> Apply[[#2]] & Colors}]
```

Code sample:

```
Take[a, 2]

{{42., 41., 41., 41., 41., 21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 
  11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 41., 21., 52., 52., 52., 52., 52., 
  52., 52., 52., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 52., 52., 41., 
  52., 52., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 52., 52., 95., 95., 42., 21., 95., 90., 90., 41., 95., 95., 
  11., 11., 95., 11., 11., 11., 95., 95., 95., 95., 90., 90., 90., 
  95., 90., 90., 90., 90., 41., 41., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 
  81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 71., 71., 71., 41., 41., 41., 21., 41., 
  11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 
  11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 
  90., 90., 41., 21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 95., 95., 41., 
  41., 41., 95., 71., 71.}, {42., 41., 41., 41., 21., 21., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 21., 21., 21., 21., 21., 
  21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 11., 11., 
  11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 41., 41., 21., 
  52., 52., 52., 52., 52., 52., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  52., 52., 52., 41., 52., 52., 52., 52., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 52., 52., 52., 21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 41., 41., 41., 41., 52., 52., 52., 52., 42., 42., 22., 90., 
  95., 90., 41., 41., 95., 11., 95., 95., 11., 95., 95., 95., 90., 
  90., 90., 90., 41., 90., 90., 95., 90., 90., 90., 41., 41., 81., 
  81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 81., 41., 71., 41., 
  41., 41., 21., 41., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 
  11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 11., 
  11., 11., 11., 90., 90., 90., 90., 21., 21., 41., 41., 41., 41., 
  41., 95., 95., 90., 95., 95., 95., 41., 71., 71.}}

Colors

{{"0.", RGBColor["0.00000000000", "0.00000000000", 
   "0.00000000000"]}, {"11.", 
  RGBColor["0.27843137255", "0.41960784314", 
   "0.62745098039"]}, {"12.", 
  RGBColor["0.81960784314", "0.86666666667", 
   "0.97647058824"]}, {"21.", 
  RGBColor["0.86666666667", "0.78823529412", 
   "0.78823529412"]}, {"22.", 
  RGBColor["0.84705882353", "0.57647058824", 
   "0.50980392157"]}, {"23.", 
  RGBColor["0.92941176471", "0.00000000000", 
   "0.00000000000"]}, {"24.", 
  RGBColor["0.66666666667", "0.00000000000", 
   "0.00000000000"]}, {"31.", 
  RGBColor["0.69803921569", "0.67843137255", 
   "0.63921568628"]}, {"41.", 
  RGBColor["0.40784313726", "0.66666666667", 
   "0.38823529412"]}, {"42.", 
  RGBColor["0.10980392157", "0.38823529412", 
   "0.18823529412"]}, {"43.", 
  RGBColor["0.70980392157", "0.78823529412", 
   "0.55686274510"]}, {"51.", 
  RGBColor["0.64705882353", "0.54901960784", 
   "0.18823529412"]}, {"52.", 
  RGBColor["0.80000000000", "0.72941176471", 
   "0.48627450980"]}, {"71.", 
  RGBColor["0.88627450980", "0.88627450980", 
   "0.75686274510"]}, {"72.", 
  RGBColor["0.78823529412", "0.78823529412", 
   "0.46666666667"]}, {"73.", 
  RGBColor["0.60000000000", "0.75686274510", 
   "0.27843137255"]}, {"74.", 
  RGBColor["0.46666666667", "0.67843137255", 
   "0.57647058824"]}, {"81.", 
  RGBColor["0.85882352941", "0.84705882353", 
   "0.23921568628"]}, {"82.", 
  RGBColor["0.66666666667", "0.43921568628", 
   "0.15686274510"]}, {"90.", 
  RGBColor["0.72941176471", "0.84705882353", 
   "0.91764705882"]}, {"95.", 
  RGBColor["0.43921568628", "0.63921568628", "0.72941176471"]}}
```

Comment: try `ArrayPlot[a, ColorRules -> (Rule@@@Colors)]` or `ArrayPlot[a /. (Rule@@@Colors)]` ?

Comment: None of them work, it's still gray-scale :/. Maybe the problem comes from the data types of Colors.

Comment: pnz, could you post a  small portion of  your `a` and `Colors`?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this, as you are importing strings:

```
Colors = ToExpression@ReadList["nlcd-colors.csv", {"Word", "Word", "Word", "Word"}, 
 WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}];
rules = ColorRules -> Flatten@{IntegerPart@ToExpression@#[[1]] -> 
   RGBColor[#[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]] & /@ Colors}
ArrayPlot[IntegerPart@a, rules]
```

[image]

### Edit

Including the style of and suggestions by @kglr:

```
Colors = ReadList["nlcd-colors.csv", {"Word", {"Word", "Word", "Word"}}, 
WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}] /. x_String :> ToExpression[x];

rules = ColorRules -> Flatten@{IntegerPart@#[[1]] -> RGBColor @@ #[[2]] & /@ Colors};
ArrayPlot[IntegerPart@a, rules]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Colors` have `String`s inside. For example,

```
Colors[[2]]
```

> {"11.", RGBColor["0.27843137255", "0.41960784314", "0.62745098039"]}

After replacing strings with expressions

```
Colors = Colors /. x_String :> ToExpression[x];
```

and using

```
ArrayPlot[a, AspectRatio -> 1/10, ColorRules -> (Rule @@@ Colors)]
```

or

```
ArrayPlot[a /. (Rule @@@ COlors), AspectRatio -> 1/10]
```

we get

[image]

Comment: I have to learn many things from all like you when using WL elegantly ;))..

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, thank you for the upvote and kind words.

Comment: Colors = ToExpression@
   ReadList[
    "d:\\bitbucket\\diversity\\data\\nlcd\\nlcd-colors.csv", {Word, 
      RGBColor[Word, Word, Word]} /. x_String :> ToExpression[x], 
    WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}];

ToExpression::notstrbox: RGBColor[0.00000000000,0.00000000000,0.00000000000] is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language input.

Unfortunately, it's not working :/